# Testing Login Component fails with Error: Expected false to be truthy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the login functionality where the submit button should be disabled when all input fields are empty, but the test shows error : Expected false to be truthy. while it works for rest of the cases

## login.component.html

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-2">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="col-md-4 form-control" id="email" name="email" ngModel required/>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-2">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="col-md-4 form-control" id="password" name="password" required ngModel minlength="6"/>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
          {{ isLoginMode ? "Login" : "Sign Up" }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

## =================================
login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';  
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';  
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';  
import { LoginService } from './login.service';  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-login',  
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']  
})  
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoginMode = false;  
  alertMessage: string = null;  
  @ViewChild('loginForm', { static: false }) loginForm: NgForm;  

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }  

  ngOnInit(): void {  
  }  
}
```

## =====================================
login.component.spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';  
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';  
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';  
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';  

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';  
import { LoginService } from './login.service';  

describe('LoginComponent', () => {  
  let component: LoginComponent;  
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;  
  let submitEl: DebugElement;  
  let loginService: LoginService;  
  let loginFormEl: DebugElement;  
  let email: HTMLInputElement;  
  let password: HTMLInputElement;  

  beforeEach(async () => {  
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({  
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],  
      imports: [FormsModule , HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule]  
    })  
    .compileComponents();  
  });  

  beforeEach(() => {  
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);  
    component = fixture.componentInstance;  
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    loginFormEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("form"));  
    submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));  
    email = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=email]');  
    password = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=password]');  
  });  

  it('should check initially input fields are empty', () => {  
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    expect(email.value).toBe('');  
    expect(password.value).toBe('');  
  });  


// This is failing (Error: Expected false to be truthy.)  
  xit('should test if submit button is disabled when the form is invalid -- Required fields are empty', () => {  
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    fixture.whenStable().then( () => {  
      component.loginForm.form.controls['email'].setValue("");  
      component.loginForm.form.controls['password'].setValue("");  
    })  
   expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();  
  });  


it('should test if submit button is enabled when the form is valid',() => {  
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    fixture.whenStable().then( () => {  
      component.loginForm.form.controls['email'].setValue("test@test.com");  
      component.loginForm.form.controls['password'].setValue("123456789");  
    })  
   expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();  
  });  
});
```

Comment: Try calling  `fixture.detectChanges();  ` before the `expect`

Comment: Thanks for the response but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. I don't think HTML attributes need to be tested at all.
2. You can still do this using something like this:

```
// This is failing (Error: Expected false to be truthy.)  
  xit('should test if submit button is disabled when the form is invalid -- Required fields are empty', () => {  
    component.loginForm.form.controls['email'].setValue(null);  
    component.loginForm.form.controls['password'].setValue(null);  
    fixture.detectChanges();  
    fixture.whenStable().then( () => {      
      expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeTruthy();  
    })  
  });
```

Instead of testing for empty strings, try setting null values and it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but setting null values is also not working